# E22 49cc mini chopper

Tags: troubleshooting

SEARCH IN THE CURRENT
AND SHOW ME
Index
Mi
49cc E22 wiring help needed
Just got my first mini chopper, wiring was a mess, so I'm starting over, and I am greatly confused. The wires coming from the engine, mine has two sets. I need to know what they go to. A simple wiring diagram with pics would be great. And I'd like to know the bare bones wiring to see if it's gonna run. Just the kick start will do. If it's gonna run ok. Then I will wire up the key the electric start etc. I believe this has a switch on the throttle side on brake thing that has to be depressed to start/run? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!